# What is the goal of '-fuse-ld=gold' flag?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, address-sanitizer

I am playing around with [Google Sanitizers](https://github.com/google/sanitizers) and there is one flag - `-fuse-ld=gold`. I am not sure that understood the idea from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)) page.

For example, using CMake

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=gold")
```

Could you possibly share your opinion?

Answer (score 5):

The -fuse-ld=gold flag indicates that the gold Linker should be used.
gold is a Linker from Google:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)